Assigning TCustomForm.PopupParent causes RecreateWnd and reset Top/Left properties
I found out that if you assign TCustomForm.PopupParent, the window is recreated (function RecreateWnd). This resets the parameters left / top / width / height assigned after the form was created.
How can this be avoided?
I came up with only this code:
saveLeft := formForShow.Left;
saveTop := formForShow.Top;
saveWidth := formForShow.Width;
saveHeight := formForShow.Height;

formForShow.PopupParent := PopUpParentForModal;

formForShow.HandleNeeded; // create window handle
formForShow.SetBounds(saveLeft, saveTop, saveWidth, saveHeight);
Result := formForShow.ShowModal;

How correct is it to do this and is there a more beautiful way?

You can't avoid the window recreation (even ShowModal itself can trigger it), but recreating the window should not lose the Form's current properties. If it is losing values, that is a bug that should be reported to Embarcadero.

This doesn't look like a bug, since this behavior is forced into TCustomForm.CreateParams -> if (not(csDesigning in ComponentState) or (Parent = nil)) and (FPosition in [poDefault, poDefaultPosOnly, poScreenCenter]) then
begin
X := Integer(CW_USEDEFAULT);
Y := Integer(CW_USEDEFAULT);
end;

That code is using a default position only if the Form's Position is poDefault... or poScreenCenter. If you want to use exact positioning, you should be using poDesigned instead. But I still consider it a bug that the window's current position would not be preserved during a window recreation.

From TCustomForm.PopupMode documentation

The PopupMode property is automatically set to pmAuto when the
ShowModal method is called. However, this causes the window handle to
be recreated, which is not usually desirable. To avoid the re-creation
of window handles, you can explicitly set the PopupMode property to
pmAuto prior to calling the ShowModal method (such as at design time).

So I suggest that you follow advice from the documentation and set the PopupMode property accordingly.

but i don't use PopupMode, i use PopupParent property. When PopupParent is set, the PopupMode value is automatically set to pmExplicit

I know you use PopupParent but in your scenario you will have to use PopupMode in conjunction with PopupParent to solve your problem.

You seem to have missed my post that setting PopupParent and PopupMode are linked. It doesn't make sense to set both properties, since setting one changes the other.

The quoted documentation is misleading. ShowModal does not set the PopupMode to pmAuto. However, it does treat the PopupMode as-if it were pmAuto if it is actually set to pmNone. ShowModal recreates the window if PopupMode is pmNone and Application.ModalPopupMode is not pmNone.
